# Does android AnimationDrawable has any quick import tool?

Tags: android, animationdrawable

I want to create a Animation Drawable just like this example from google,

```
<!-- Animation frames are wheel0.png through wheel5.png
    files inside the res/drawable/ folder -->
<animation-list android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel0" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel3" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel4" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel5" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
```

Seems I need to assign all drawable and its duration one by one to animation.  It will be a dull work when I have hundred of drawable need to assign in.

Does there has any tool to help this?
Or any way that could make this better?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to using a hundred drawables is to create the animation programmatically.

Something like:

```
    AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
    for (int i=10; i <= 15; i++) {
         int resourceId = getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("wheel" + i, "drawable", getContext().getPackageName()); 
         animation.addFrame(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), resourceId), 50);
    }
    animation.setOneShot(false);
```